Can Hezbollah be distinguished from Lebanese army soldiers?
The ceasefire agreement between Israel and Lebanon says that the Lebanese army should send troops the the south of Lebanon, whereas all other militant groups (including Hezbollah) should move north of the Litani river.
To verify that the agreement is respected, there should be a way to distinguish between Hezbollah soldiers and Lebanese Army soldiers. But I do not see how they can be distinguished: what prevents Hezbollah soldiers from simply wearing Lebanese Army uniform and moving to South Lebanon to maintain their presence there? How will they be detected, technically?

Presumably the Lebanese Army keeps records of what soldiers it has, e.g. for payroll purposes. And most armed forces have some kind of ID card. But how do you tell that someone wearing an Israeli uniform is actually an Israeli soldier - it depends how devious you consider people to be and what they are prepared to do (steal uniforms, use false IDs, genuinely join the armed forces under a false identity, use Mission: Impossible-style rubber face masks, fake DNA tests and biometrics....) Sorry but this is a dumb question.

Well, I think there have been a few Israeli strikes motivated by claims of Hezbollah activity since the ceasefire.  So, if the wish is for future stability, asking about the agreement's safeguards wrt hostile identification, and hostile infiltration methods, is germane to current events and not "a dumb question".

This will probably not be incredibly advertised to the general public as to the details of how it works, but the same way Israel didn't attack LAF soldiers much thus far and didn't have much trouble telling apart LAF facilities from Hezbollah weapon caches. (These got bombed throughout Lebanon, not just in the south.) There will surely be a 'deconfliction' line on which to ask "are these your soldiers"? Among other things like intel gathering that doesn't require the cooperation of the LAF.

The radio.
The Israeli Defense Force and Lebanese Armed Forces do talk to each other. They have done so for a long time too.
While Lebanon and Israel do not have diplomatic relations, the LAF and IDF have had limited communication to avoid accidental LAF casualties.
In some cases, the IDF simply warns the LAF that they're about to bomb some guys. The LAF can then advise if its their guys moving or not.
Primarily, it is the IDF notifying the LAF of impeding action, and the LAF responding. It would be inaccurate to say the LAF cooperates with the IDF, or assists the IDF in any capacity.
Outside of talking, the IDF has good intelligence.
The IDF has a good idea on the assets of each organization, where they are located, what types, and how many.
A lot about how movements are being conducted is revealing; where they are going and where they are coming from, how large/small the group is, and what types of equipment they have. This all adds to the intelligence aspect.
Israel also tries to intercept the internal communications of the LAF and Hezbollah.
There may be some additional classified ways, too.
However, in my opinion, Hezbollah has very little to gain by trying to look like the LAF. Hezbollah doesn't have much in the way of heavy equipment. Most of the military equipment Hezbollah uses can be carried in and more easily disguised as civilian equipment.

Classified sources are useful for internal purposes, but as the USA and France are also part of the deal, Israel would probably have to prove to them that the deal was breached, and classified sources would be less useful for this.

(IMHO, this Q seems harshly judged:  while ceasefires are always welcome in stopping ongoing deaths, badly-balanced, or badly-implemented ones can just end up causing trouble down the line.  Look at Minsk #1 and #2 for example.  I am not saying that's the case here, but... ).
The actual full text of the agreement refers to other things which might be easier to distinguish:

(preamble) These understandings reflect steps to which Israel and Lebanon are committed in order to implement fully UN Security Council Resolution (UNSCR) 1701, recognising that UNSCR 1701 also calls for full implementation of its predecessor UNSC resolutions, including "disarmament of all armed groups in Lebanon", so that the only forces authorised to carry arms in Lebanon will be the Lebanese Armed Forces (LAF), Internal Security Forces, Directorate of General Security, General Directorate of State Security, Lebanese Customs and Municipal Police (hereinafter “Lebanon's official military and security forces"). To that end, the US and France understand the following



In order to implement UNSCR 1701, and upon the commencement of the cessation of hostilities according to paragraph one, the Government of Lebanon will provide all necessary authorities, including freedom of movement, to Lebanon's official military and security forces, and instruct them, consistent with UNSCR 1701 and its predecessor resolutions to:



a. Monitor and enforce against any unauthorised entry of arms and related materiel into and throughout Lebanon, including through all border crossings, and against the unauthorised production of arms and materiel within Lebanon.


b. Starting with the Southern Litani Area, dismantle all existing unauthorised facilities involved in the production of arms and related materiel, and prevent the establishment of such facilities in the future.


c. Starting with the Southern Litani Area, dismantle all infrastructure and military positions, and confiscate all unauthorised arms inconsistent with these commitments.



Upon the commencement of the cessation of hostilities according to paragraph one, and without prejudice to Unifil and its mandate and responsibilities in UNSCR 1701 and its predecessor resolutions, Israel and Lebanon resolve, in co-ordination with Unifil, to reformulate and enhance the tripartite mechanism (hereinafter: “the Mechanism”). The reformulated and enhanced Mechanism, hosted by Unifil, chaired by the US, and including France, will monitor, verify, and assist in ensuring enforcement of these commitments.


So... one way to read this is that the LAF is in charge of carrying out the work.  But the US and France, not just the UN, will have a part in the verification procedures.  That's a good start towards addressing the Q.


Upon the commencement of the cessation of hostilities according to paragraph one, Israel will withdraw its forces in a phased manner south of the Blue Line, and in parallel the LAF will deploy to positions in the Southern Litani Area shown in the attached LAF Deployment Plan, and will commence the implementation of its obligations under the commitments, including the dismantling of unauthorised sites and infrastructure and confiscating unauthorised arms and related materiel. The Mechanism will co-ordinate execution by the Israel Defence Forces and LAF of the specific and detailed plan for the phased withdrawal and deployment in these areas, which should not exceed 60 days.


There's more verbiage to be found.  But what it seems to mean is that even successfully disguised Hezbollah groups would not have access to equipment and facilities to do much, in theory.
The Lebanese Armed Forces are theoretically charged with enforcement, but I guess they were to do so as well in 2006.  Allowing disguised Hezbollah to pretend to be LAF would clearly be a breach of the agreement.  And then when it comes to actual firing, of course that would also annul the ceasefire if not brought under control.  Keep in mind too that getting mistaken for Hezbollah puts LAF at risk from Israel so their motivations to go along with such tricks are limited.
Even for Hezbollah itself that is not without drawbacks.  Remember they are only really appreciated by the Shiite community, about 30% of Lebanese.  While disguising themselves in other ways, say in IDF uniforms may contravene the laws of war, that wouldn't necessarily upset too many people.  Doing so in LAF uniforms might be both a loss of face and make them even less popular with the Lebanese people.
Israel had obvious reasons to not keep the IDF in Lebanon itself, longterm and thus exposed to IED/ambushes.  And the cost/benefit ratio, to Israel, of keeping combat going was probably degrading over time, after the initial successes.  In any case, the IDF studiously avoided pushing their land incursion into Lebanese territory very far, staying within 2-5km of the border so control and direct verification had to be left to third parties.
This looks solid enough, but it all boils down to how it actually gets implemented and how it ages over time.  The original resolution 1701 didn't end up getting enforced all that much in its later years, but it did stop combat in 2006.
Nothing is ever all that certain in wars.  And doubly so when Lebanon, as the signatory, has a limited actual capacity to enforce its will over Hezbollah, even assuming good intentions.

This doesn't even make an attempt to answer the question. I'm not sure how it got upvoted the question is quite literally "what prevents Hezbollah soldiers from simply wearing Lebanese Army uniform and moving to South Lebanon to maintain their presence there?" and the answer to that is nothing (if they actually join the Army and take orders from the state). It's entirely allowed by the agreement. This is what my answer addresses. Apparently people didn't like that.

LOL.  At least I understood the question was about Lebanon, not Ukraine.
